# How to use inverse link functions on gamm mgcv model

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I used inverse link functions,

```
ilink <- family(gam_model)$linkinv
```

for create time series interaction graph, and it works wonderful.

I replace my model to gamm model, for consider autocorrelation in my model. Is it possible to use inverse link function on gamm model? I tried

```
ilink <- family(gamm_model)$linkinv
ilink <- family(gamm_model$gam)$linkinv
ilink <- family(gamm_model$lme)$linkinv
```

But for all the options it show the errors:

Error in UseMethod("family") : 
  no applicable method for 'family' applied to an object of class "c('gamm', 'list')"

Error in UseMethod("family") : 
  no applicable method for 'family' applied to an object of class "gam"

Error in UseMethod("family") : 
  no applicable method for 'family' applied to an object of class "lme"

The second option is surprising because it works on the origin gam model, calss "gam"

Thank you
Dvora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those unfortunate side effects of `mgcv::gamm()` being a bit of a kludge.

The `$gam` component does actually contain a `$family` component it's just that the `$gam` object is *only* of class `"gam"` whereas a `mgcv::gam()` model object *also* inherits from class `"glm"` and there is a `family.glm` method for that. I believe this is due to the `$gam` object not being a fully compliant `"gam"` object and hence not a full `"glm"` object, hence it not inheriting from `"glm"`,. It could also just be an oversight; for a long time the object returned by `mgcv::gamm()` was simply of class `"list"`!

The easiest way to proceed would be to write your own `family` method for objects of class `"gamm"` (so you don't have to remember which component to extract from) and for class `"gam"`:

```
family.gamm <- function(object, ...) {
    family(object$gam)
}

family.gam <- function(object, ...) {
    object$family
}
```

Given that the definition of `family.glm` matches exactly that of the `.gam` method above, having this hang around in your workspace isn't going to interfere with the rest of *mgcv*.

```
library("mgcv")
set.seed(1)
dat <- gamSim(1, n = 400, dist = "normal", scale = 2, verbose = FALSE)
m1 <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data = dat, method = "REML")
m2 <- gamm(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data = dat, method = "REML")

family(m1)
family(m2)
```

Producing

```
> family(m1)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

> family(m2)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity
```